# how to copy a part of a raw image

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to copy selected part of a raw image to another image

I get start and end position as percentage and by that I can calculate the start and end position in width

how can I copy that selected part to another raw image?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a `Texture2D`, you can do the following:

1. Calculate A texture start/end X (dX)
2. Create a new Texture2D (B), sized as dX and full Y
3. Call `A.GetPixels()`
4. Iterate on array copying pixels to new texture
5. Apply on new texture

Pseudo code:

```
var aPixels = aTexture.GetPixels();
var bWidth = endX - startX;
var bTexture = new Texture2D(bWidth, endY);
var bPixels = bTexture.GetPixels();

for (int x = startX; x < endX; x++) 
{ 
  for (int y = 0; y < endY; y++) 
  { 
    var aIndex = x + y * A.width;
    var bIndex = (x - startX) + y * bWidth;
    bPixels[bIndex] = aPixels[aIndex];
  } 
}

bTexture.Apply();
```

Note that my code quite possibly won't work; as I'm typing this on a mobile phone.

Comment: makes sense but couldnt able to work it. 
can you write in detail when you have the chance please?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Image Processing is an expensive process for CPUs, so I don't recommend it in Unity,
But anyway, For your image and in this special case, I think you can crop your image by changing the Size and Offset of texture in material.

**Update:**

This is an example of what I mentioned:
[image]
You can calculate Tile and Offset based on the dragged mouse position on Texture. ([Check Here](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html))

Answer (score 0):

I found this.
you can set start coordinates and width and height to GetPixels();

````
void Start () {
     public Texture2D mTexture;
     Color[] c = mTexture.GetPixels (startX, startY, width, height);
     Texture2D m2Texture = new Texture2D (width, height);
     m2Texture.SetPixels (c);
     m2Texture.Apply ();
     gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.mainTexture = m2Texture;
 }
```
````